# Differences between interface and abstract class

Tags: oop, interface

I was going through the differences between Interface versus Abstract class on MSDN but got some confusion on below difference:

If you anticipate creating multiple versions of your component, create an abstract class. Abstract classes provide a simple and easy way to version your components. By updating the base class, all inheriting classes are automatically updated with the change. Interfaces, **on the other hand, cannot be changed once created. If a new version of an interface is required, you must create a whole new interface**

I have confusion on this line 
**on the other hand, cannot be changed once created. If a new version of an interface is required, you must create a whole new interface****

Could you help explain?

Answer (score 1):

methodes you write in the interface you should obligatory put it in your class Which implements in the iterface

and the abstract class is the opposit of interface the methodes you put in class abstract you can use it in your class or not.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract base class is a class whose sole intent is to be derived. An interface is the set of public methods of a concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

While they differ very little in actual functionality, I like to think of interfaces as an adjective while an abstract class is a noun. For the classic instance of an animal, an interface is used do describe attributes, like pet-able, friendly, dangerous. On the other hand, an abstract class would describe the thing itself more narrowly, like canine, feline or human.